# PHP Login Redirection - redirects on second attempt

Tags: php, session, redirect

This is my php script of `prc_login.php`

```
<?php
include ("a_functions.php");
$u_UName    = $_REQUEST['u_UName'];
$u_Password = md5($_REQUEST['u_Password']);
if($_SESSION['loginsec']==$_REQUEST['loginsec']){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loginsec'])) unset($_SESSION['loginsec']);
    $loginquery = $db->where("u_UName",$u_UName)->where("u_Password",$u_Password)->getOne("tbl_users","u_Id");
    if($db->count){
        $_SESSION['u_Id'] = $loginquery['u_Id'];
        $redirect = "index.php";
        $_SESSION['notify']="Wow!! Welcome";
    } else {
        $redirect = "login.php";
        $_SESSION['notify']="Please check login details or password";
    }
} else {
    $redirect = "login.php";
    $_SESSION['notify']="Please login through proper channel.";
}
header("location:$redirect");
exit();
?>
```

session is started in `a_functions.php` and `$db` defined as `Mysqlidb` class object and `$_SESSION['loginsec']` is declared in `login.php`

Now that, when I login from `login.php` for the first time, the script redirects to `login.php`. And again I login for second time, then only it redirects to `index.php` and works fine.

Why I am redirected back to `login.php` at my first attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("location: ".$redirect);
exit();
```

//try this one may be helps you

Comment: Yes! this is working. Thank you. But still with previous script, it was redirecting at second attempt only. What would be the reason?